# SWRevealController swipe gesture

Tags: ios, swift, swrevealviewcontroller, uiswipegesturerecognizer

My problem is that swipe gesture is available on each `UIViewController` of `front's` `UINavigationController` stack, while I would like it to be available only on first one, how should I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the `SWRevealViewControllerDelegate`, probably this method can be helpful:

```
// Implement this to return NO when you want the pan gesture recognizer to be ignored
optional public func revealControllerPanGestureShouldBegin(_ revealController: SWRevealViewController!) -> Bool
```